# Append only if there is input (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following jQuery which shows any input in a div container

```
jQuery('#container').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.which == 32) {             
            var cont = jQuery(this).val().replace(/,/g, "");
            var data = 'Something';  //Show the input
            cont.push(cont);
            jQuery('.container ul').append(data);
            jQuery(this).val('');
        }               
});
```

The keyup here is the spacebar (32). So, whenever a spacebar is used, any words prior to is appended in the div (.container ul).

Now, even if there is no input, if spacebar is used, it still appends the data (empty).

Is there a way to check and only enable the append function if there is input?

Thanks

Comment: Before `cont.push` just check if `cont.trim() == ''`. If it is, you can just return at that point.

Comment: Ah, i see. of course. Thanks man!

Comment: I guess I'll post that as an answer than. I wasn't sure if that was what you were really going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `cont.push` just check if `cont.trim() == ''`. If it is, you can just return at that point.

```
jQuery('#container').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which == 32) {             
        var cont = jQuery(this).val().replace(/,/g, "");
        var data = 'Something';  //Show the input
        if (cont.trim() === '') { return; }
        cont.push(cont);
        jQuery('.container ul').append(data);
        jQuery(this).val('');
    }               
});
```